# Writing to sqlite 3 databse by combining 2 tables

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have two tables, customers and lessons. I want to write date and time to my lessons table in the correct row with the correct customer id. I want to get the customer Id from the customer table using the username that the customer entered when logging in and then use that customerid to insert the date and time into the right place. Here is my code:

```
with sqlite3.connect('sqlite.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()
    custid = c.execute('SELECT customerid FROM customers WHERE customerusernm = @username2')
    print(custid)
    c.execute('INSERT INTO lessons(lessondt,lessontm) VALUES (dt,tm) WHERE custid = customerid')
    connect.commit()
    connect.close()
```

I am getting this error on the line with the select statement:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

How do I fix this and is there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide a tuple with the value that should be bound where you wrote "@username2". Try the following:

```
with sqlite3.connect('sqlite.db') as db:
            c = db.cursor()
    # set the variable to the username you want to compare to
    username = 'some username'
    custid = c.execute('SELECT customerid FROM customers WHERE customerusernm = @username2', (username,))
    print(custid)
    c.execute('INSERT INTO lessons(lessondt,lessontm) VALUES (dt,tm) WHERE custid = customerid')
    connect.commit()
    connect.close()
```

Depending on how you retrieve the username, you could use the `getpass` module:

```
import getpass    

username = getpass.getuser()
```

Comment: The username will change with different customers, so how do i account for that. With this method I can only compare to one particular username for only one user

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for exactly. Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: you suggested that i should have a variable called username where i will hold the username i want to compare to in my database. However, that username will only be for one user. If another user logs in with a different username then how would the value of the username variable change?

Comment: I added a comment on the getpass module that retrieves the username of the user logged in to the computer. 
Or is there a special username for this program only that the user logs in with? Then you probably handle the username elsewhere in the program and have to pass it to the username variable.

Comment: thanks for the reply. your suggestion worked out. However, now on the INSERT INTO lessons line, i'm getting the error : ```sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error```

Comment: The small code part you provided does not give me enough context to know what your program exactly does - sorry. Maybe open a new question for that.
You could also mark my answer as the one helping you out - since I assume it solved your problem.